# Moving dfferent File extension files from one location to other location in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

```
var outputDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(@"G:\Local\Syndicationtest");
var sourceDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(@"G:\Local\Syndicationtest");
var sourceFiles = sourceDirectory.GetFiles();
foreach (var item in sourceFiles)
{
    FileHelper.Copy(item, outputDirectory);
    FileHelper.Move(FileHelper.Zip(item), new DirectoryInfo(@"G:\Local\Syndicationtest\History"));

}
```

I need to move files based on file type extension in other words the source files contains all types of extension files, I need to filter the file types of following ".xml", ".dat", ".txt", ".csv", ".zip", ".doc" and only move those files to destination location

Comment: `if (acceptableExtensions.Contains(item.Extension)) //do whatever you want`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So how about this:

```
var ext = new List<string> { ".xml", ".dat", ".txt", ".csv", ".zip", ".doc" };
var sourceFiles = sourceDirectory.GetFiles()
                                 .Where(f => ext.Contains(f.Extension.ToLower()));
```

This solves two things:

1. Gives you the list you want.
2. Gets you away from the three character extension issue that exists with the `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles(string searchPattern)` overload.

Comment: @user2271011, please see my edit. I'm not used to using the `DirectoryInfo` interface and just got it confused.

Comment: @user2271011, I'm glad I could be of assistance!

Comment: What about string comparison? what if the extension is a different case?

Comment: @TraeMoore, good call. I checked the M$FT code and they are not lowering it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `Path.GetExtension()`

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension.aspx)

Your code:

```
var outputDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(@"G:\Local\Syndicationtest");
var sourceDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(@"G:\Local\Syndicationtest");
FileInfo[] sourceFiles = sourceDirectory.GetFiles();
var extensions = new List<string> { ".xml", ".dat", ".txt", ".csv", ".zip", ".doc" };

foreach (FileInfo item in sourceFiles)
{        
    if(extensions.Contains(item.Extension))
    {
        FileHelper.Copy(item, outputDirectory);
        FileHelper.Move(FileHelper.Zip(item), new DirectoryInfo(@"G:\Local\Syndicationtest\History"));
    }   
}
```

Michael Perrenoud's solution is preferred if you'd like to use LINQ.

Comment: Okay, you have a `FileInfo` which has an `Extension` property. Even easier. :) Edited.

Answer (score 0):

here you go..

you will need to change the directory names.

```
class Program 
{
    public static string outputDirecotry = @"C:DebugCopy";

    public static void Main()
    {
        var fileExtenstions = new List<string>
            {
                ".xml",
                ".dat",
                ".txt",
                ".csv",
                ".zip",
                ".doc"
            };

        foreach (var path in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:Debug")
                 .Where(path => fileExtenstions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(path).ToLower())))

            File.Copy(path , Path.Combine(outputDirecotry , Path.GetFileName(path)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can get the `LastIndex` of `.` in filePath and read till the end to get the extension.

then you can verify with required set of Extensions.

Try This:

```
                    var outputDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(@"G:\Local\Syndicationtest");
                    var sourceDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(@"G:\Local\Syndicationtest");
                    String[] FileExt = new String[] { ".xml", ".dat", ".txt", ".csv", ".zip", ".doc" };
                    var sourceFiles = sourceDirectory.GetFiles();

                    foreach (var item in sourceFiles)
                    {
                        if ((item.Contains(".")) && (FileExt.Contains(item.Substring(item.LastIndexOf("."), 4))))
                        {
                            FileHelper.Copy(item, outputDirectory);
                            FileHelper.Move(FileHelper.Zip(item), new DirectoryInfo(@"G:\Local\Syndicationtest\History"));
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: No, use Path.GetExtension()

Comment: What if the file extension contains more or less that 3 characters? `item` is already a string.

Comment: Thanks for your Inputs. 1.OP wants to check with only 3 characters thats why i used 3( any how Thanks for giving suggestion to use Path.GetExtension() i will use that) 2.Yes item is String i have edited my Answer.

Comment: @Sudhakar what if the if we have file name some thing like this abcd.lll.dat or xxyyy.2013.11.12_14.43.7574.csv

Comment: then it will be .dat and .csv thats why i'm taking LastIndexof  dot operator , please let me know if anything more is required.

Comment: Your assumption that the extension will be three characters will bite you.

Comment: @Locke: Thanks for your valuable inputs, anyhow Path.GetExtension() is much better option as suggested by others, please check it from Sam Leach comments. Thanks a lot.